# The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.3 is invalid

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, pom.xml

I am getting following error while executing command mvn package -DSkipTests under the project folder in my ubuntu machine.

The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details Nov 05, 2015 4:04:31 PM org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.Logs$JULSink warn WARNING: Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo

My pom is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns = 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0' xmlns:xsi= 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org  /xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd'>
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.se</groupId>
 <artifactId>MobileApp</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
 <name>MobileApp</name>
 <modules>
   <module>Mob-ak</module>
    <module>Mob-as</module>
    </modules> 
 <build>
<plugins>
    <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your project is a jar/war or pom? because you have : < packaging >pom< / packaging >

Comment: ya its pom packaging